# In Apache Solr How to retrieve deleted documents

Tags: java, indexing, solr

Whenever I am indexing Documents using solr ,my core deleted documents count also getting increased .I want to see the documents which are getting deleted.

Comment: If they're marked as deleted when you're indexing, it's old documents being replaced with more recent ones - i.e. the old version of the document is deleted and a new one takes it place. Unless you're issuing explicit deletions as part of your indexing process, that's likely what's happening. The deleted documents will still be present in the index files, so you can use Luke with a small modification to see those as well: https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/issues/105

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach a Listener and log entries before they will be deleted.
You can also write them inside a custom file which contains only deleted entries details.

You can implement your own logic too with that code example when you delete entries :
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_solr/apache_solr_deleting_documents.htm

```
import java.io.IOException;  

import org.apache.Solr.client.Solrj.SolrClient; 
import org.apache.Solr.client.Solrj.SolrServerException; 
import org.apache.Solr.client.Solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient; 
import org.apache.Solr.common.SolrInputDocument;  

public class DeletingAllDocuments { 
   public static void main(String args[]) throws SolrServerException, IOException {
      //Preparing the Solr client 
      String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/Solr/my_core"; 
      SolrClient Solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();   
      
      //Preparing the Solr document 
      SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();   
          
      //Deleting the documents from Solr 
      Solr.deleteByQuery("*");        
         
      //Saving the document 
      Solr.commit(); 
      System.out.println("Documents deleted"); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Hi, this will help me hereafter the documents getting deleted but I want to retrieve already deleted documents.is there any way ?

Comment: Retrieve deleted documents is done with looking at your backups only. Hope you have done some backups before.
If they are marked as "deleted" there is a small chance you can get them because you can find them inside your indexes. But no guarantee at all.